# Como saber se um número é inteiro ou um float? E como atribuir um tipo a um valor inserido na função input

Tags: python

Eu tenho o seguinte problema:

> Faça um programa que receba dois números quaisquer (inteiros ou reais) e imprima na tela os números inteiros que estão no intervalo compreendido por eles.

E fiz a seguinte solução:

```
  n1 = int(input("Digite um valor:"))
  n2 = int(input("Digite um valor:"))

  for i in range(n1,n2):
      f(i == int(i)):
          print(i)
```

Porém tenho alguns problemas:

1. Como eu posso fazer com que a função `input` pegue valores de
   apenas 2 tipos? No caso inteiro ou `float`.
2. Como validar se um determinado número é real ou inteiro? Eu tentei pelo tipo, mas não sei se tem outra maneira
3. Como fazer o `range` levar em conta o número final do intervalo?

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade você não precisa verificar se é inteiro ou `float`. Basta usar [`float(input(...))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float), que também aceita strings contendo números inteiros, assim você converte o que foi digitado para um número.

Sugiro capturar também o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), caso não tenha sido digitado um número. Para facilitar, crie uma função que lê o número e já retorna o valor ajustado para o `range`:

```
def ler_numero(mensagem):
    while True:
        try:
            f = float(input(mensagem))
            n = int(f)
            if f == n:
                return n
            else:
                return n + 1
        except ValueError:
            print('Digite um número válido')
```

Esta função pede que seja digitado um número, e caso dê erro (ou seja, não foi digitado um número), ela pede que seja digitado novamente.

Se a conversão para `float` der certo, eu retorno um inteiro, levando em conta se a parte decimal é zero (se ele for 4.0, por exemplo, então eu retorno 4, e se for 4.1, 4.2, etc, eu retorno 5). Para isso eu uso [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), que arredonda o `float` para baixo (em caso de números positivos - para valores negativos, veja mais abaixo).

Eu faço esses ajustes porque um `range` [só aceita inteiros](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Então agora basta pedir para digitar os números e imprimir o `range`:

```
inicio = ler_numero('Digite o valor inicial:')
fim = ler_numero('Digite o valor final:')

for i in range(inicio, fim):
    print(i)
```

---

Não está claro se o valor final deve ser incluso (se o final for 4.0, deve imprimir 4 ou não?). O código acima considera que não. Se quiser considerar que sim, sempre deve somar 1 depois de converter para inteiro (mas somente para o valor final, já que o inicial é incluso).

Outro detalhe é que o código acima não funciona para números negativos, pois `int(-3.5)` resulta em `-3` e ao somar 1, o início seria `-2` (ou seja, o `-3` seria deixado de fora do `range`).

Então bastaria mudar a função para usar [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=floor#math.floor), que arredonda para baixo (`math.floor(-3.5)` resulta em `-4`, e ao somar 1, o início é `-3`, incluindo-o no `range`):

```
import math

def ler_numero(mensagem):
    while True:
        try:
            f = float(input(mensagem))
            n = math.floor(f)
            if f == n:
                return n
            else:
                return n + 1
        except ValueError:
            print('Digite um número válido')
```

E na leitura dos números, você também pode incluir uma validação para verificar se o valor inicial é menor que o valor final (caso contrário não faz sentido prosseguir):

```
while True:
    inicio = ler_numero('Digite o valor inicial:')
    fim = ler_numero('Digite o valor final:')
    if fim <= inicio:
        print('Valor final deve ser maior que o inicial')
    else:
        break # valores corretos, sai do loop

for i in range(inicio, fim):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -2):

Realmente da maneira como o hkotsubo disse é melhor, mais prático e mais pythônico. Mas apenas para título de registo: Sim, é possível verificar se um número é float e você pode fazer isso de diferentes maneiras. Algumas delas:

Através do método [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
x = 9.2
print(isinstance(x, int))
>>false
print(isinstance(x, float))
>>true
```

Ou ainda com a função [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
x = 9.2
print(type(x))
>><class 'float'>
```

Comment: Mas isso é apenas quando você já possui o objeto destes tipos. A questão é identificar o *tipo* vindo pelo `input`, que sempre retorna uma `string`. Tem uma pergunta aqui no SOpt que trata disso, verei se acho.

Comment: O título da pergunta é "Como saber se um número é inteiro ou um float", então acho que minha resposta não é tão distante. Além do mais creio que pode servir ao que ele se propõe

Comment: Mas você não deve responder ao título e sim à pergunta. `isinstance` não serve pra nada nesse caso, porque `input` sempre retorna `str` então nunca vai ser nem `float` nem `int`; A sua resposta só serve pra confundir ainda mais o principiante.